# Not able to get form values to action class

Tags: java, struts2

This is my code, I am not able to get form value to action class in struts2, I tried request.get and using bean, but not able to do it. Please help.

I have tried doing `request.get` and using bean, it didn't work, can you tell me how can I get the value. I want to get `docKey` value from jsp and process it and do some operation on it.

```
public String execute(){

    try {
        //HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
        Connection connection = (Connection) DriverManager  
                .getConnection(  
                "jdbc:sqlserver://myipaddress:51433;databaseName=dbname;selectMethod=cursor",  
                        "user", "passwd");  

        System.out.println("DATABASE NAME IS:"  
                + connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
        System.out.println("");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs = statement  
        .executeQuery("select createdOn,ReceivedOn,docKey from table where   docKey=?");
         //rs.setString(1, Mssql.bean.getdocKey());
       // I want to get that docKey value from jsp/////
        while (rs.next()) {  
            //System.out.println("createdOn:" + rs.getString("createdOn"));
            bean bean = new bean();
            bean.setdocKey(rs.getString("docKey"));
            bean.setcdate(rs.getString("createdOn"));
            bean.settstamp(rs.getString("ReceivedOn"));
        }  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 


    return "check";

This is my jsp
     <s:form action="Mssqltest">
     <tr>
     <td> 
     <s:textfield name="docKey" label="docKey"></s:textfield>  
     </td>
     <s:submit value="Get Records"></s:submit>
     </tr>
     </s:form>

    This is my struts.xml

     <action name="*Mssqltest" class="Mssql.IRcheckairtel"  method="{1}">
    <result name="check">airtelresult.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: y u commented //rs.setString(1, Mssql.bean.getdocKey()); ??

Comment: because, that was not working. This is my bean public String getdocKey() {
  return docKey;
 }
 public void setdocKey(String docKey) {
  this.docKey = docKey;
 }

Comment: r u able to access the user populated value by Mssql.bean.getdocKey() ??

Comment: No, that is my problem, I am not getting that value

Answer (score 0):

From our discussions I understand that you are accessing the form fields as `Struts1.x`  in `struts2` its very easy

if it is your JSP

```
 <s:form action="Mssqltest">
 <tr>
 <td> 
 <s:textfield name="docKey" label="docKey"></s:textfield>  
 </td>
 <s:submit value="Get Records"></s:submit>
 </tr>
 </s:form>
```

when you want that `docKey` value in your `Action class` create a getters and setters in your Action class as the same name of the field in JSP page.

like below

```
   private String docKey;
   public String execute(){
      try {
    //HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
    Connection connection = (Connection) DriverManager  
            .getConnection(  
            "jdbc:sqlserver://myipaddress:51433;databaseName=dbname;selectMethod=cursor",  
                    "user", "passwd");  

    System.out.println("DATABASE NAME IS:"  
            + connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
    System.out.println("");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs = statement  
    .executeQuery("select createdOn,ReceivedOn,docKey from table where   docKey=?");
     rs.setString(1, Mssql.bean.getdocKey());
   // I want to get that docKey value from jsp/////
    while (rs.next()) {  
        //System.out.println("createdOn:" + rs.getString("createdOn"));
        bean bean = new bean();
        bean.setdocKey(rs.getString("docKey"));
        bean.setcdate(rs.getString("createdOn"));
        bean.settstamp(rs.getString("ReceivedOn"));
    }  
} catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} 


   return "check";
 }

 public String getDocKey()
   { 
      return docKey;
       }
 public void setDocKey(String docKey)
    {
       this.docKey = docKey;
    }
```

here in your class you are accessing `docKey` from some `bean` class that is the mistake you are doing wherever you are using the `docKey` you just use that with `getDockey()` it will return the value that has entered in JSP .

Your `getter` and `setter` for `docKey`

Change them to

```
 public String getDocKey() 
  {
      return docKey;
    } 
public void setDocKey(String docKey) 
   { 
      this.docKey = docKey; 
   }
```

Change that format of the methods I mean `getXX` getter Capital letter and settet Capital letter

Comment: It is asking to change the bean to statc, when I uncomment this line   rs.setString(1, bean.getDocKey());  Can I do that?

Comment: You should  uncomment that First check using `System.out.println(getDocKey);` whether that value is available or not ?

Comment: I changed my bean like this  and tried to print that value, but I am not getting that value public static String getDocKey() {
  return docKey;
 }
 public void setDocKey(String docKey) {
  this.docKey = docKey;
 }

Comment: `bean` what is that Are you talking about `struts2` in struts2 accessing the form fields are very easy just create a getters and setter of that name of the field in your action class .

Comment: Yes I did that, you can see my code above, but I am not getting the value in my action class. I mean I changed getter and setter like this

Comment: mssql.jsp  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="Mssqltest">
<tr>
<td> 
   <s:textfield name="docKey" label="docKey"></s:textfield>  
</td>
<s:submit value="Get Records"></s:submit>
</tr>
</s:form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: "jdbc:sqlserver://myipaddress:port;databaseName=dbname;selectMethod=cursor","user", "psswd");    System.out.println("DATABASE NAME IS:"  
                  + connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println("");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs = statement  
                    .executeQuery("select createdOn,ReceivedOn,docKey from EuroRawData where docKey=?");
            //rs.setString(1, bean.getDocKey());
            System.out.println(Mssql.bean.getDocKey());

Comment: not able to post fulll code, it is not allowing me to do it

Comment: Thank you it worked, but I have a question, I cannot use getter and setter which is there in some other class? is that not possible ?

Comment: That glad to hear. Now you can accept the answer. When reading form data you have to follow as I mentioned in my answer you can use other class beans to set the data in Action class . Better you read Struts2 documentation or online tutorial.